# 楽天レシピAPI取得後、JSONに変換したい

Tags: swift, json, api

楽天レシピAPI取得後、
「try JSONSerialization.jsonObject」でJSONに変換しようとしたのですが、
print文で中身を確認したところ、下記のように表示され、変換されませんでした。
キャスト部分に問題があるのでしょうか。API自体に問題があるのでしょうか。
ご教示いただけますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
["result": {
    large =     (
                {
            categoryId = 30;
            categoryName = "\U4eba\U6c17\U30e1\U30cb\U30e5\U30fc";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/30/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 31;
            categoryName = "\U5b9a\U756a\U306e\U8089\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/31/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 32;
            categoryName = "\U5b9a\U756a\U306e\U9b5a\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/32/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 33;
            categoryName = "\U5375\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/33/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 14;
            categoryName = "\U3054\U98ef\U3082\U306e";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/14/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 15;
            categoryName = "\U30d1\U30b9\U30bf";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/15/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 16;
            categoryName = "\U9eba\U30fb\U7c89\U7269\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/16/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 17;
            categoryName = "\U6c41\U7269\U30fb\U30b9\U30fc\U30d7";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/17/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 23;
            categoryName = "\U934b\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/23/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 18;
            categoryName = "\U30b5\U30e9\U30c0";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/18/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 22;
            categoryName = "\U30d1\U30f3";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/22/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 21;
            categoryName = "\U304a\U83d3\U5b50";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/21/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 10;
            categoryName = "\U8089";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/10/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 11;
            categoryName = "\U9b5a";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/11/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 12;
            categoryName = "\U91ce\U83dc";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/12/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 34;
            categoryName = "\U679c\U7269";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/34/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 19;
            categoryName = "\U30bd\U30fc\U30b9\U30fb\U8abf\U5473\U6599\U30fb\U30c9\U30ec\U30c3\U30b7\U30f3\U30b0";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/19/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 27;
            categoryName = "\U98f2\U307f\U3082\U306e";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/27/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 35;
            categoryName = "\U5927\U8c46\U30fb\U8c46\U8150";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/35/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 13;
            categoryName = "\U305d\U306e\U4ed6\U306e\U98df\U6750";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/13/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 20;
            categoryName = "\U304a\U5f01\U5f53";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/20/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 36;
            categoryName = "\U7c21\U5358\U6599\U7406\U30fb\U6642\U77ed";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/36/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 37;
            categoryName = "\U7bc0\U7d04\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/37/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 38;
            categoryName = "\U4eca\U65e5\U306e\U732e\U7acb";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/38/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 39;
            categoryName = "\U5065\U5eb7\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/39/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 40;
            categoryName = "\U8abf\U7406\U5668\U5177";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/40/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 26;
            categoryName = "\U305d\U306e\U4ed6\U306e\U76ee\U7684\U30fb\U30b7\U30fc\U30f3";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/26/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 41;
            categoryName = "\U4e2d\U83ef\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/41/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 42;
            categoryName = "\U97d3\U56fd\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/42/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 43;
            categoryName = "\U30a4\U30bf\U30ea\U30a2\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/43/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 44;
            categoryName = "\U30d5\U30e9\U30f3\U30b9\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/44/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 25;
            categoryName = "\U897f\U6d0b\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/25/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 46;
            categoryName = "\U30a8\U30b9\U30cb\U30c3\U30af\U6599\U7406\U30fb\U4e2d\U5357\U7c73";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/46/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 47;
            categoryName = "\U6c96\U7e04\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/47/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 48;
            categoryName = "\U65e5\U672c\U5404\U5730\U306e\U90f7\U571f\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/48/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 24;
            categoryName = "\U884c\U4e8b\U30fb\U30a4\U30d9\U30f3\U30c8";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/24/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 49;
            categoryName = "\U304a\U305b\U3061\U6599\U7406";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/49/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 50;
            categoryName = "\U30af\U30ea\U30b9\U30de\U30b9";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/50/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 51;
            categoryName = "\U3072\U306a\U796d\U308a";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/51/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 52;
            categoryName = "\U6625\Uff083\U6708\Uff5e5\U6708\Uff09";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/52/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 53;
            categoryName = "\U590f\Uff086\U6708\Uff5e8\U6708\Uff09";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/53/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 54;
            categoryName = "\U79cb\Uff089\U6708\Uff5e11\U6708\Uff09";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/54/";
        },
                {
            categoryId = 55;
            categoryName = "\U51ac\Uff0812\U6708\Uff5e2\U6708\Uff09";
            categoryUrl = "https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/55/";
        }
    );
    medium =     (
    );
    small =     (
    );
}]
```

```
 //リクエスト
 let task : URLSessionTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
                        
  do {
     let recipeData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, 　　　options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : Any]

  print(recipeData)
                               
 }
 catch{

  print(error)
 }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON形式のAPIについて少し勘違いをしておられるようです。

まず、
***「楽天レシピAPI」は元々結果をJSON形式で返しています。それを「JSONに変換」する必要はありません***

APIの返したJSON text形式のデータを見たければ、`try JSONSerialization.jsonObject`の**前** に次の一行を入れてみて下さい。

```
        print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

---

また、
***`JSONSerialization.jsonObject`はJSON形式のデータからiOS/Objective-C/(Swift)で扱えるデータ型に変換するもの*** です。

「JSONに変換」するためのメソッドではありません。

変換後の結果は以下のようなデータ型になります。

```
JSON object → NSDictionary
JSON array  → NSArray
JSON string → NSString
JSON number → NSNumber
true/false  → NSNumber
```

あなたのコードでは、変換後に一番外側の`NSDictionary`をSwiftの`Dictionary<String, Any>`型にさらに変換しているので、「Swiftの`Dictionary`形式」「`NSDictionary`形式」「`NSArray`形式」などが入り混じった形式で`print(recipeData)`の結果が表示されています。

`print(error)`ではなく`print(recipeData)`が実行されていると言うことは、

***元のデータは正しいJSON形式であり、`JSONSerialization.jsonObject`での変換は成功した***

と言うことになります。

---

`print(recipeData)`の結果がJSON形式になっていないのは当たり前なので、そんなことは気にせずに**取得したデータをどう使うか**、を気にして下さい。

例えば、以下のようなコードを実行すると、

```
    do {
        
        if
            let jsonData = data,
            let recipeData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as? [String : Any],
            let result = recipeData["result"] as? [String: Any],
            let large = result["large"] as? [[String: Any]]
        {
            for category in large {
                print(category["categoryName"] as? String ?? "")
                print(category["categoryUrl"] as? String ?? "")
            }
        } else {
            print("Bad data", data)
        }
    } catch{
        print(error)
    }
```

(このAPIの場合、`JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments`は意味を持たないと思われるので、`options:`の指定は省略してあります。)

こんな出力が得られます。

```
人気メニュー
https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/30/
定番の肉料理
https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/31/
定番の魚料理
https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/32/
卵料理
https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/33/
ご飯もの
https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/14/
パスタ
https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/15/
麺・粉物料理
https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/16/
汁物・スープ
https://recipe.rakuten.co.jp/category/17/
...(以下略)
```

---

何か疑問点などありましたら、この回答へコメントしてお知らせください。